# How to Sync data from one amazon RDS to another?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Hi i am pretty new to Amazon RDS.my question how to Sync data from one amazon RDS machine to another? like taking a mysql Dump or something like that, and is it possible to Sync over multiple regions like from Europe RDS Machine to US RDS machine.

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you want to sync data.  Do you want to do it automatically, and just make database B be a copy of A?  Or, what if A and B have some rows with the same internal primary key, but different other information, which database do you want to be the 'master'?  This question needs a lot more detail supplied.  Also, read up on http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/#Multi-AZ - that may answer some of your questions.